# Ionic v3 Social Sharing Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework

Im working on adding social sharing to an Ionic app. I would like to data coming from my CMS to populate the data needed for the Social Sharing Plugin but I cannot get the syntax right. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<ion-content class="home">
<button default (click)="share('{{post.name}}', '{{post.desk}}', null, '{{post.url}}')">Share</button>
<button default (click)="shareViaTwitter('{{post.name}}', null, '{{post.url}}')">Share on Twitter</button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: why are you not calling functions to implement social sharing

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: also what is `post`. and why are you using `{{}}` there?